Meaning of 生まれ持ったセンス
This is a description of the character コウジ, who is very strong and can fight with a large group of people without getting injured:

コウジは「集団にやられる」という言葉が似合わない男。ほとんどの奴らはコウジは力が強いだけで大した技はもってないと誤解しているが生まれ持ったセンスがある。

I am uncertain about the meaning of 生まれ持ったセンスがある. It means to possess an innate "sense"? Who has 生まれ持ったセンス? コウジ or ほとんどの奴ら?


Who has 生まれ持ったセンス?

It's コウジ. The structure is (ほとんどの奴らはコウジは力が強いだけで大した技はもってないと誤解しているが)([コウジは]生まれ持ったセンスがある). = Although most people mistakenly think that コウジ is only strong in power and doesn't have significant skills, he has an innate "sense".
This usage of センス is probably tricky. It's obviously directly borrowed from English "sense", but I don't think this meaning is identical. 広辞苑 states:

物事の微妙な感じをさとる働き・能力。感覚。 The function/ability to perceive subtle feel of things.

(Also see kotobank).
I think it's closer to taste in some regard.  ファッションセンス fashion sense (I was certain it wouldn't make sense in English but maybe it does?) means something like one's taste in styles (of clothes).  ユーモアのセンス is sense of humour.
Regarding skills, it's like being sensible and well skilled - mostly not by verbalised learning, but more from experience and/or a talent.
So...    コウジ has innately got the "hang of it", he just knows it, he's talented --- regarding fights.
